# get_comment_meta not behaving as expected

Tags: comments, comment-form, comment-meta

I'm sure this must be a silly error by me but I haven't been able to solve it...

I added an extra 'rating' field to my comments form so that users can rate posts. Everything works fine and by using `add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'rating', $rating )` it gets inserted fine in the `wp_commentmeta` table.

However, when I try to retrieve the value using `get_comment_meta( comment_ID(), 'rating', true )` I'm getting the comment ID instead of the rating value.

Any ideas on what could be wrong? Thanks in advance...

FIXED:

comment_ID() echoes the ID. What I needed was `get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'rating', true )`

Comment: Please, post the answer in the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is what you need to use.

```
<?php echo get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', $rating ); ?>
```

IDs are already stored in `$comment` array.